# Finding splitting field of a polynomial over $Z_3$

Tags: field-theory

I have to find the splitting field of $f(x)$ = $x^2+x +2$ over $Z_3$.

This polynomial is irreducible over $Z_3$.

I tried finding the factors of $f(x)$ in $\mathbb C$ and they turned out to be $a=(x+1/2+(\sqrt{7}/2)i)$ and $b=(x+1/2-(\sqrt{7}/2)i)$

Then, i considered $Z_3(a,b)$,but i don't know how to proceed further

to find its splitting field ?

Intuitively i think it should be $Z_3(i)$ , but i am not sure.

Comment: What do you know about finite extensions of finite fields?

Comment: @Arthur Nothing really, i have just started studying about extension fields,and so far have just been through some basic stuff like the Kronecker's theorem,splitting fields,zeros of an irreducible polynomial.

Comment: What can you say about the degree of the splitting field over $\mathbb{Z}_3$? And do you know how many extensions of this degree $\mathbb{Z}_3$ has?

Comment: Ittay Weiss (+1) explains this in generality. Just offering another bit, because it just happens that the formula for finding the roots of a quadratic works, **when viewed correctly**, over any field of characteristic $\neq2$. In the field $\Bbb{Z}_3$ you have $7=1$, because $7\equiv1\pmod3$. Consequently you should think that $\sqrt7=\sqrt1=1$, and this certainly works, if we (as is sufficient for the purposes of using quadratic formula) mean by $\sqrt a$ an element $b$ with the property $b^2=a$. Therefore you only need to think about adjoining $i$, or just $\sqrt{-7}$.

Comment: @Arthur Well, i think, the degree of the splitting field over $\mathbb Z_3$ should be equal to 3 for any zero of the given polynomial. But i don't think i know how many of these extensions should $\mathbb Z_3$ have.

Comment: You should probably follow Ittay Weiss's reasoning then. For the record the degree of the field extension (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_field_extension) has to be equal to $2$, and there is a unique field extension of degree $n$ of a finite field (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#Uniqueness).

Answer (score 1):

First, you should clear a confusion you have. There is no point in looking at factoring the polynomial over $\mathbb C$. The ground field is $\mathbb Z_3$, and so $\mathbb Z(i)$ has nothing to do with the solution, since it does not contain $\mathbb Z_3$.

Somewhere in your notes you should have the following theorem. If $f(X)\in K[X]$ is irreducible, and $\alpha $ is a root in some extension field, then $K(\alpha)$ is isomorphic to the quotient ring $K[X]/(f(X))$. So, in your case, the splitting field is given by $\mathbb Z_3[X]/(f(X))$. You can work out what its elements are (hint: it has 9 elements) and what the addition and multiplication tables are.